# Wrap text on space and slash

Tags: html, css

I have a div/textarea field where I want to wrap the data on 50 characters `without breaking the word`. The text contained in the element will be a path which can contain alphanum, spaces and slashes. I want it to be wrapped at spaces and slashes. Is this feasible with css only without requiring any js to perform this action

I have used

```
<textarea cols=50 style="border:none;font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: #333;">document vault/12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890/asdasd 22</textarea>
```

this should appear as(expected)

```
document vault/
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
/asdasd 22
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: can you show your code here so that we can review first

Comment: updated the question. I have tried using textarea for space wrapping but didnt find anything for wrapping on slash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cause line to wrap to new line after 100 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754608/cause-line-to-wrap-to-new-line-after-100-characters)

Comment: @aavrug - i dont want word break here. have already tried it

Comment: `font-family:monospace; overflow: hidden;` is the closest but `cols` has to be `46` with the system I'm on and it wraps at `<space>` and `-` naturally as the default browser behavior.  I don't think `/` is possible without some JavaScript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011756/what-characters-will-a-textarea-wrap-at-other-than-spaces

Comment: Another trick seems to be adding a zero-width space after the slashes.  Not a `CSS` solution, but certainly doesn't require any JS. :)  WARNING:  Copy/paste to a terminal shows this as a full space, so I would recommend using it for display only (not if copying/pasting TextArea content elsewhere)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16279315/3196753

Comment: @QZSupport - it does looks promising though we cannot have a fixed width here for 50 characters

Comment: @Varun can you elaborate?  Do you mean the `TextArea` must display as wider than 50 characters, yet still break on 50 characters?

Comment: i actually want the row to have a maximum of 50 characters and wrap without breaking the word. I guess i need CSS + JS for this trying one solution will update if it works

Comment: negative vote for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used width:50ch and replaced all \ with ​\​ this helped. thanks all for your suggestions. Special thanks to `QZSupport`

```
a=a.replace(/\\/g, "&#x200b;\\&#x200b;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css property with the text line you want alphanumerics to be in a single line .

`white-space: nowrap;`